# jQuery code no longer working in v1.8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am following a jQuery [tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/) and its code seems to work fine with jQuery 1.4.3, but I need it to work with jQuery 1.8.3.

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/auBbz/

**Problem:** When I switched the version of jQuery used to version 1.8.3, after replacing `className` with `class`, the selectbox that shows in the `Result` pane does not have any text inside `<div class="selectBox"></div>`.

**jsfiddle after making the change:** http://jsfiddle.net/auBbz/1/

What other changes did I miss out?

Comment: what is incorrect with updated fiddle ? for me it shows dropdown... only styles/images incorrect

Comment: I do not see any text inside `<div class="selectBox"></div>`

Comment: you mean just after load ?

Comment: After everything on the page has loaded, I see the background of `#selectBox` but theres no text inside it.

Comment: jQuery is built into jsFiddle you know.  It could be confusing to others to set jsFiddle to `Mootools` while including `jQuery` in the `body` pane.

Comment: Opps I forgot about that, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the more major changes between 1.4 and 1.6 was with `attr()` method and introduction of `prop()` method to be used for properties that aren't really attributes.

`selectedIndex` would be considered a property not an attribute. Your code is returning `undefined` for `attr('selectedIndex')`. Use `prop('selectedIndex')` instead

DEMO :  http://jsfiddle.net/auBbz/3/

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following is bad and outdated.

Remove this condition:

```
if(i==select.attr('selectedIndex')){
          selectBox.html(option.text());
      }
```

add the following before loop:

```
selectBox.html(select.find('option:selected').text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/auBbz/2/

The tutorial is bad because it uses `attr` on non standart attributes of html, and as they knew 1.4.2 introduced the `data()` method, which cover this. well. also every `option` which selected in `select` has `selected` attribute, so i not understnad the reason to use custom attribute when there is standard one present.